# Tensorflow installation issue on windows "tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on th is platform."

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pip, tensorflow

[image]

I am not able to install tensorflow on windows, the pip is working correctly but still this issues is there ..

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? TensorFlow on Windows requires the **64-bit version** of Python **3.5**.

Answer (score 0):

i was solved same problems, look this image
[Screenshoot of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZiSy.png)
before cuntinue, you maybe look at this requirement : Python 3.5 & Windows64 bit, check out this on python site.
at least, before i wuse 2.7th version of Python (maybe later for ure version)..

I uninstall a previously python version, and install a 3.5.2 version
and this link for download

Finally it's done
this [Screenshoot Was Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leYeV.png)

I hope this answer will help u to resolve.. best regards :)

Comment: Note, I use windows 10 x64 version

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you've got Python 3.5.2 **(64-bit version)** installed on your computer, which you can do it [here.](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/)  Then, add its path to your environment variable, the path may look something like *C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35*. After you've followed these steps try to install TensorFlow via PIP.

Note - TensorFlow supports only 64-bit Python 3.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this worked. Python 3.5.2 and pip 9.0.1