# Tensorflow on windows - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, windows-7-x64

I'm using Anaconda 3.1.0 on Windows 7 64 bit. I have installed tensorflow(GPU). I am getting errors while running following command.

`>>> import tensorflow as tf`

***The complete traceback***

```
    (tensorflow) C:\windows\system32>python
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v
.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in s
wig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 919, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <
module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in s
wig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in s
wig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 919, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <
module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in s
wig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\mbharsakale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\l
ib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: As clearly stated in the TF [webpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) `The Anaconda installation is community supported, not officially supported.` ... so I would recommend you installed it with the alternative (that is **pip**) or move to a *nix OS distribution.

Comment: I tried with pip but still faced same problem.

Comment: I created a test script that can help diagnose problems with your installation (mostly due to missing directories in the `%PATH%` environment variable). You can download it here: https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c

Comment: Try to add the cudnn lib path into the PATH environmental variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone. cudnn lib version was wrong, so I replaced correct version lid and it worked.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want the cudnn64_6.dll, not the cudnn64_5.dll https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cudnn lib version was wrong, so I replaced correct version of cudnn lib and it worked.

Comment: Tensorflow 1.3 need cudnn V6, make sure you have a cudnn64_6.dll in the folder C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Cudnn\cuda\bin and this path into the environment variable

Comment: Did you try with only CPU Version, Only CPU version does not need cudnn lib right?

Answer (score 12):

Installing `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2019` resolved the described problem for me

Tested on Windows 10 for Python 3.6 (Anaconda) and Tensorflow 2.1.0

Comment: This worked for me after searching high and low for a solution - thanks for mentioning it.  (Windows Server 2016 - Standard)

Comment: Also worked for me, Windows 10 relatively fresh install.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same error. The problem is not with the python or tensorflow versions but the dependencies required for it from the windows operating system. Just follow the following steps and you are good to go.

- Go to this link https://www.sts-tutorial.com/download/credistributable2019
- Download the vc_redist.x64.exe (64-Bit) or vc_redist.x86.exe (32-Bit), according to your system.
- Execute the file and restart your PC.
- Now import the tensorflow, it should work.

Comment: Great! I had tried everything, finally this is all I had to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I used to get this kind of error.

The reason that I had installed the `wrong and mismatched versions` of **Tensorflow backend** and **Keras**

The versions I fixed that has worked perfectly for me can be seen as below

- Tensorflow 2.0.0 (`2.1.0` throws the error)
- Keras version 2.3.1

Best,

Comment: Tensorflow 2.1.0 works perfectly on my ubuntu machine at work, but your solution to use tensorflow 2.0.0 worked on my windows machine at work!

Comment: Yes, i used Windows for the work. I hope Tensorflow version 2.1.0 would throw **no error** in Linux. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Win10 could not find the module because the environment variable cuDNN was not set correctly!

You need to set the env var to the `bin` subfolder. In my case as I extracted it to `C:`, I had to add `C:\cuda\bin` to the `path` system varaible.
For more infos, checkout [this](https://medium.com/@soumyadipmajumder/complete-guide-to-tensorflow-gpu-installation-on-windows-10-36e5858640e9).

Or relate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622526/5392548) for checking the compatiblity of the versions.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow has few issues with python3.6.
Try with python 3.5.2. 
pip install tensorflow
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue: [Latest Supported Visual C++ Downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

> Install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019. Starting with the TensorFlow 2.1.0 version, the msvcp140_1.dll file is required from this package (which may not be provided from older redistributable packages). The redistributable comes with Visual Studio 2019 but can be installed separately:
>
> - Go to the Microsoft Visual C++ downloads:
>   Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-?c-downloads
> - Scroll down the page to the Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 section.
>   ?- Download and install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio >2015, 2017 and 2019 for your platform.
> - Make sure long paths are enabled on Windows.
>
> Install the 64-bit Python 3 release for Windows (select pip as an optional feature).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. The problem is not with the python or tensorflow versions but the dependencies required for it from the windows operating system. Just follow the following steps and you are good to go.

1. Go to this link
   https://www.sts-tutorial.com/download/credistributable2019
2. Download the vc_redist.x64.exe (64-Bit) or vc_redist.x86.exe
   (32-Bit), according to your system.
3. Execute the file and restart your PC.
4. Now import the tensorflow, it worked for me and it can work for
   yours too
   credits to that guy , i had missed his id