# Tensorflow-gpu not installed properly in windows machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, cudnn

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu in my new windows system. But am encountering this error

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

This question has been asked before and I have gone through those but I am not able to figure why this is not working.

[Tensorflow on windows - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503603/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10033

I have added all the paths to the environment variables based on this post
https://medium.com/@viveksingh.heritage/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-version-with-jupyter-windows-10-in-8-easy-steps-8797547028a4

The versions I am using are

```
Python: 3.6.7 
CUDA: 10.0.130
cuDNN: 7.3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF supports CUDA 9.0.

Follow these instructions

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try using Anaconda

[See this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc)

Summarizing:
1. Install Miniconda or Anaconda and then go to "Anaconda Prompt": simple use Windows and start to write "anaconda" after installing: it should appear.
2. Now, simply run:

conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu

Done! To be sure, you can test it:

In "Anaconda Prompt":

```
Activate environment using ‘activate tf_env’.
Go to python console using ‘python’
```

In Python, just write:

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

Info about your card should appear.
Now, just create a new project in your IDE, choosing "Existing Interpreter", selecting the Virtual Envirment that we just created ("tf_gpu"), and your new files inside the project will run on the gpu.

Hope I helped! Thanks to Harveen Singh (I tried many tutorials, before seeing one that worked and was easy)