# Trouble Installing Keras and TensorFlow in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Keras in Anaconda Python on my 64 bit Windows 10 computer that does not have a GPU(I don't know if that is significant or not). I called `pip install keras` and that seemed to install smoothly. However calling `import keras` gives this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\Code\JohnWorkspaces\Machine_Learning\BeginningWithPydev\main\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via pip install tensorflow
```

So I go and install tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow`. It seems to take a while, though eventually it installs, yet does nothing to fix my problem, and still gives me the above error. Calling `import tensorflow` gets me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\Code\JohnWorkspaces\Machine_Learning\BeginningWithPydev\main\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\jsmith\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The only solutions I have found for this issue are downgrading TensorFlow and installing Visual Studio. I have heard that Visual Studio is a very large program and would like to refrain from installing it. As for downgrading TensorFlow, I feel there should be a better solution. What is it about Visual Studio that makes TensorFlow work, and is there a way I can get that(Certain DLLs or dependencies) without having to get everything else along with Visual Studio?
These are links to places I have seen this:

1. [Tensorflow on windows - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503603/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could)

2.https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749

3.https://medium.com/@mdiqbalbajmi00786/importerror-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-e9f128c5fbf6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [tensorflow installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install),
you should have pre installed [C++ redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) for windows 7 or later.

Also you can directly download the tensorflow wheel from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) just make sure to choose correct operating system, architecture and python version while downloading. Then you can do

```
pip install path_t_wheel_file.whl
```

> I have heard that Visual Studio is a very large program and would like to refrain from installing it.

You do not have to install entire visual studio just the [C++ redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

> What is it about Visual Studio that makes TensorFlow work,

I haven't looked into tensorflow's source code but I think It is written in `C++` so it requires additional libs that are provided by the c++ redistributables

Answer (score 0):

This may help
create new environment don't install packages in base environment (optional but it fixed tensorflow installation bugs for me)

`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` to install tensorflow
then `pip install keras` or `conda install -c conda-forge keras`