# DLL load failed when trying to import Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build an NLP model for sentiment analysis and using keras for implementing neural network.I have install all tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu, keras with latest version and using python 3.6.6.

Here is the  initial code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I am getting error

```
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

at first line when importing tensorflow.

I have searched everything on web but i am not able to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: which OS you are using currently? are you using windows?

Comment: @Tasnuva I am using Windows 10 and python 3.6.6 in Pycharm

Comment: is it helpful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503603/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could


have you tried downgrading tensorflow version?

Comment: This is a common old problem, it has to do with version matching. Try to find an already proved working setup, even if it's with older versions. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884668/installing-tensorflow-on-windows-python-3-6-x

Comment: Thanks guys, Tensorflow : 2.0.0 works with Keras 2.3.1. My issues is resolved. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed CUDA and have completed the [setup for Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup). If this doesn't solve your problem, add more details to your question.