# Importing Tensorflow giving weird errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to learn tensor flow but when I import tensor flow

```py
import tensorflow
```

it gives errors regarding pywrap

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rakti\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\rakti\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\rakti\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\rakti\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\rakti\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rakti\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

can anyone tell me what I have done worng.
or what can I do to recover from this situation?

i have already installed cudnn and cudatoolkit

via these command line commands

```sh
conda install cudatoolkit
conda install cudnn
```

so they may not be the focus of this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow on windows - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503603/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2019` it can solve your issue because as of my research most of the places I saw, had this solution only.

If you want to know how to download it you can search google or bing about it.

Please comment if this doesn't help, I'll try to help you and make sure to install tensor flow again.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was looking after this issue since today morning. Finally got the answer in the evening from the main post regarding this issue. But still thanks a lot for posting this answer.