# Tensorflow Import error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

Tags: tensorflow

I'm unable to import tensorflow.

T/S done:

1. installed Tensorflow by following:
   https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/
   conda create -n tf tensorflow
2. installed MS Visual C++ from this discussion board:
   [Tensorflow on windows - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503603/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could)

The following is the message that I'm getting:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vb11.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019.](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

According to the docs at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Install the [64-bit Python 3 release](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) for Windows (select pip as an optional feature).