# Not able to upgrade tensorflow on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running command to upgrade tensorflow, But always getting below error.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
```

I have tried below commands :

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: That error appears at the bottom of [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884668/installing-tensorflow-on-windows-python-3-6-x?rq=1) as well -- have you tried the solutions listed there?  (More the Python version / package locations / package requirements suggestions than the Windows-specific ones)

Comment: I have tried that also I am having python 3.6 install on my mac, and pip3 also working fine but when I tried with pip3 it gives above error but using pip it is working. Don't what is happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a checklist for `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement XYZ` errors:

#### `pip` version check

What python version does the `pip` you're using refer to - is it the correct one? Imagine you have `python3.4` and `python3.5` installed and using `pip3` command that is symlinked to `pip3.4` while you assume it is symlinked to `pip3.5`. So issue first:

```
$ pip3 -V | grep -o "(.*)"
```

and verify the correct python version is printed. If it's not, then you have to find the correct `pip` executable: first check if you have version-specific commands available (e.g.

```
$ which pip3.6
```

for `python3.6`) and verify it is pointing to the correct python version with the command above (e.g. `$ pip3.6 -V | grep -o "(.*)"`). If there is no version-specific `pip`, start searching for the correct executable in the `sys.prefix`'s `bin` subdirectory. Example on my machine:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)" | xargs -I {} find {}/bin -name pip*
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
```

#### platform check

You may have a platform mismatch on your target machine. Check what platform is recognized by `pip`:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_platform())"
```

For `pip` newer than 10.0:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import pip._internal as pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_platform())"
```

The output should be `macosx_10_11_x86_64` or newer (e.g. `macosx_10_13_x86_64`). If you have an older OSX, you will have to [build TensorFlow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) because [prebuilt packages exist for MacOS 10.11 and higher only](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac).

Other platforms supported are: `manylinux1_x86_64` (so all the 64bit Linux distros with `glibc>2.5` should do just fine, no 32bit distros or some exotic ones like Alpine with `musl`) and `win_amd64` (64bit Windows).

#### ABI check

A less common problem is the ABI mismatch: you can check your platform's ABI with

```
$ python3.6 -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_abi_tag())"
```

For `pip` newer than 10.0:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import pip._internal as pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_abi_tag())"
```

The supported ABI tags are currently: `cp27m`, `cp27mu`, `cp33m`, `cp34m`, `cp35m`, `cp36m`. The above command should print you one of the tags listed. If not, you will have to build/install from sources.

#### Last notes

A rare case could be a misconfigured PyPI index: run

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow --verbose
Collecting tensorflow
  2 location(s) to search for versions of tensorflow:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow/
  * https://my.pypi.server/base/dev/+simple/tensorflow/
...
```

Check if `https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow/` is in the list. If not, try the command

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

If the installation succeeds, check if you have `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable set and clear it. If not, check if you have the file `~/.pip/pip.conf` present and if it has `index-url` entry defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualenv or anaconda to install tensorflow. I did it with anaconda on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

if you have all of the proper libraries...

```
conda install tensorflow
```

if it shows error then try

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

If the above pip install doesn't work, you might want to start from a clean anaconda install.