# pip canot find tensorflow when in virtualenv with specified python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I am experiencing a weird issue, on ubuntu 14.04 with python2.7.9 installed in a custom folder when trying to install tensorflow from inside a virtualenv that is using the custom python build pip doesn't seem to find tensorflow.

```
 virtualenv venv --python=/opt/python279/bin/python2.7
 cd venv
 source bin/activate
 pip install tensorflow
```

> Collecting tensorflow
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow

other packages install normally :/ I am utterly confused

Comment: There is this [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python2). A system requirement is `Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit)`

Comment: I don't get it, why does it work from outside the virtuealenv if that is the reason?

Comment: also it works inside the virtualenv if I use the global python2.7.6

Comment: You have a point. Did you try use this parameter `virtualenv --system-site-packages` on virtualenv creation?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot depend on system packages from my virtualenv :/

Comment: Most probably it's because your other Python 2.7.9 is compiled with different ABI flags. What does `/opt/python279/bin/python2.7 -c "import sysconfig;abiflags=('m' if sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_PYMALLOC') else '')+('u' if sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_WIDE_UNICODE') else '')+('d' if sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_PYDEBUG') else ''); print(abiflags)"` print?

Comment: it prints -> `m`

Comment: And that's your issue - Python you're using is compiled without wide unicode support (`--enable-unicode=ucs4` configuration option). For Python 2.7, tensorflow ships only wheels prebuilt for Python 2.7 built with `pymalloc` (you have that) and wide unicode (you don't have that).

Comment: You can check that by inspecting available wheels [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) - for Python 2.7, there are two wheels available: `cp27m-macosx_10_11_x86_64` for system python on MacOS and `cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64`, for Linux distros. The chars after the interpreter version are the ABI flags that the wheel requires.

Comment: @hoefling that was extremely helpful! thx; why don't you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago, I wrote [a more or less comprehensive checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342341/2650249) for possible mismatches leading to the `Could not find a version that satisfies requirement` error. Although the question is specifically about MacOS, the answer is applicable to Linux also. In your case, you have an ABI mismatch: as found out in the comments,

```
/opt/python279/bin/python2.7 -c "import sysconfig;\
    abiflags=('m' if sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_PYMALLOC') else '')+\
    ('u' if sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_WIDE_UNICODE') else '')+\
    ('d' if sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_PYDEBUG') else ''); print(abiflags)"
```

returned `m`, indicating that this Python distribution was compiled without the wide unicode support (missing the `u` flag). This means that `pip` will install only `cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64` wheels for this Python distribution. However, the only wheel [`tensorflow` offers](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) for Python 2.7 on Linux is the `cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64` one. To be able to install `tensorflow`, you'll need to build a Python 2.7 distribution with wide unicode support:

```
$ cd Python2.7-src
$ configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
$ make && make install
```