# How do I use TensorFlow GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

How do I use **TensorFlow GPU** version instead of **CPU** version in Python 3.6 x64?

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Python is using my **CPU** for calculations. 
I can notice it because I have an error:

> Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
> compiled to use: AVX2

I have installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu.

How do I switch to GPU version?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling `tensorflow` and just keep the `tensorflow-gpu` installed?

Comment: Try downloading CUDA and installing the GPU version.

Comment: That's just a warning, if you have an NVIDIA GPU, Tensorflow-gpu will automatically use that. To know more and how to disable the warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227886/4892874 To check that you're using the GPU: `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

Comment: Are you using Anaconda ? if you are you have to switch the interpreter of the particular environment in PyCharm.

Comment: Device mapping: no known devices.
I do not use Anaconda

Comment: What is your GPU?

Comment: NVIDIA 940mx, it is relative new Nvidia card.
@JorgeLeitão yes, then I have no TensorFlow

Comment: This is a top search result, so an update for 2024. As of TensorFlow 2.12, package `tensorflow-gpu` has been removed. Package `tensorflow` includes gpu support. As of TensorFlow 2.10, gpu support has been removed from Windows; the workaround is to run TensorFlow under WSL.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Follow this tutorial [Tensorflow GPU](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows-cuda-cudnn/) I did it and it works perfect.

**Attention!** - install **version 9.0!** newer version is not supported by Tensorflow-gpu

**Steps:**

1. Uninstall your old tensorflow
2. Install tensorflow-gpu `pip install tensorflow-gpu`
3. Install Nvidia Graphics Card & Drivers (you probably already have)
4. Download & Install CUDA
5. Download & Install cuDNN
6. Verify by simple program

```py
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Comment: So, CUDA 9.2 can be the problem? Should I install 9.0 then? Yesterday I had an error after installing CUDA 9.2. It said that I need DLL from CUDA 9.0 and I knew it was using GPU version, today all the time I see the error about CPU, so it is using CPU. I will try it step by step, thanks.

Comment: Yea, i had same problem about 2 month ago. I tried CUDA 9.1 and Tensorflow  doesn't support it..Then i uninstall everything and repeat all steps with CUDA 9.0 and now it works without problems.

Comment: Maybe I should ask in another question, but is tensorflow on GPU is faster than CPU at your PC? 
I tried with linear regression model and for 10000 epos and step 0.01 my CPU can calculate it in 13 second and when I use GPU it takes 39 second.

Comment: Ofc i have CPU i7 8700k and GPU nVidia GTX 1060 STRING 6GB and on GPU is faster 20 times aproximate.

Comment: Note that newer versions of tensorflow combine the cpu and gpu packages together into a single package. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: I did the same, and does tensors need to be uploaded on gpu, like they need in pytorch?

Answer (score 10):

Follow the steps in the latest version of the documentation. Note: GPU and CPU functionality is now combined in a single tensorflow package

```
pip install tensorflow

# OLDER VERSIONS pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

This is a great guide for installing drivers and CUDA if needed:
https://www.quantstart.com/articles/installing-tensorflow-22-on-ubuntu-1804-with-an-nvidia-gpu/

Comment: This should be the answer , 2022 +

Answer (score 8):

The 'new' way to install tensorflow GPU if you have Nvidia, is with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/). Works on Windows too. With 1 line.

```
conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

This is a shortcut for 3 commands, which you can execute separately if you want or if you already have a conda environment and do not need to create one.

1. Create an anaconda environment `conda create --name tf_gpu`
2. Activate the environment `conda activate tf_gpu`
3. Install tensorflow-GPU `conda install tensorflow-gpu`

You can use the conda environment.

Comment: In 2: ``conda activate tf_gpu``

Answer (score 6):

First you need to install **tensorflow-gpu**, because this package is responsible for gpu computations. Also remember to run your code with environment variable **CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0** (or if you have multiple gpus, put their indices with comma). There might be some issues related to using gpu. if your tensorflow does not use gpu anyway, [try this](https://ai-pool.com/d/tensorflow-1-13-does-not-use-gpu)

Answer (score 2):

I tried following the above tutorial. Thing is tensorflow changes a lot and so do the NVIDIA versions needed for running on a GPU. The next issue is that your driver version determines your toolkit version etc. As of today this information about the software requirements should shed some light on how they interplay:

```
NVIDIA® GPU drivers —CUDA 9.0 requires 384.x or higher.
CUDA® Toolkit —TensorFlow supports CUDA 9.0.
CUPTI ships with the CUDA Toolkit.
cuDNN SDK (>= 7.2) Note: Make sure your GPU has compute compatibility >3.0
(Optional) NCCL 2.2 for multiple GPU support.
(Optional) TensorRT 4.0 to improve latency and throughput for inference on some models.
```

And [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) you'll find the up-to-date requirements stated by tensorflow (which will hopefully be updated by them on a regular basis).

Answer (score 2):

For `conda` environment.

- `conda search tensorflow` to search the available versions of tensorflow. The ones that have `mkl` are optimized for CPU. You can choose the ones with `gpu`.
- Then check the version of your cuda using `nvcc --version` and find the proper version of tensorflow in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) page, according to your version of cuda.
- For example, for cuda/10.1,and python3.8, you can use

  - `conda  install tensorflow=2.2.0=gpu_py38hb782248_0`

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, even though the tensorflow website [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_source_configurations) mentions that CUDA 10.1 is compatible with tensorflow-gpu-1.13.1, it doesn't work so far. tensorflow-gpu gets installed properly though but it throws out weird errors when running.

So far, the best configuration to run tensorflow with GPU is CUDA 9.0 with tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0 under python3.6.

Following this configuration with the steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51307381/2562870 (the answer above), worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall tensorflow and install only tensorflow-gpu; this should be sufficient. By default, this should run on the GPU and not the CPU. However, further you can do the following to specify which GPU you want it to run on.

If you have an nvidia GPU, find out your GPU id using the command `nvidia-smi` on the terminal. After that, add these lines in your script:

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = #GPU_ID from earlier

config = tf.ConfigProto()
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

For the functions where you wish to use GPUs, write something like the following:

```
with tf.device(tf.DeviceSpec(device_type="GPU", device_index=gpu_id)):
```

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, I have installed only NVIDIA graphics card drivers (only for the display, not CUDA and CUDNN). I followed your instructions, i.e.

```
echo 'Name of the TENSORFLOW ENVIRONMENT:'
read ENVNAME

#CREATING THE ENV
conda create --name $ENVNAME -y

#ACTIVATE THE eNV
conda activate $ENVNAME6

# INSTALLING CUDA DRIVERS
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0 -y

# INSTALLING TENSORFLOW
conda install tensorflow-gpu -y
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel -y
conda install ipykernel -y

# ADDING ENV TO JUPYTER LIST
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=$ENVNAME

# 'VERIFY GPU SUPPORT'
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; 
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

But I am getting back the following message:

```
>python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

Output> []
```

Does that mean that my python can't see my Graphic Card?

At this point it's worth mentioning that my graphics card is an NVIDIA geforce gtx 560, and on the NVIDIA site it says the compatible cards are "geforce gtx 560 TI, geforce gtx 560M". Does this mean my graphics card is not CUDA compatible, and if so why when I install numba and run the following code it seems to work:

```
from numba import jit, cuda
import numpy as np
# to measure exec time
from timeit import default_timer as timer   

# normal function to run on cpu
def func(a):                                
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[i]+= 1      

# function optimized to run on gpu 
@jit(target_backend='cuda')                         
def func2(a):
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[i]+= 1
if __name__=="__main__":
    n = 10000000                            
    a = np.ones(n, dtype = np.float64)
    
    start = timer()
    func(a)
    print("without GPU:", timer()-start)    
    
    start = timer()
    func2(a)
    print("with GPU:", timer()-start)
```

Comment: I am quite new in here and stackoverflow doesn't let me to write you back, in the comment area, so I hope to see  this one! @Tikendra Kumar Sahu : I did what you suggested but still it doesn't work!

Comment: I finally found why tensorflow-gpu doesn't work in my case: it is related with the drivers. 

-If anyone is looking for system requirements for tensorflow-gpu that can be found in the following link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

"....The following NVIDIA® software is required for GPU support only: NVIDIA® GPU Drivers version 450.80.02 or later... ."

-Also using the following link: https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx?lang=en-us
we see the latest driver for geforce gtx 500 series is 391

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33887850)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps:

1. Update your graphics driver to latest and proprietary.(not open source)
2. Run the simple script I have created to Create conda virtual environment and Download all necessary requirements [Script here](https://github.com/tikendraw/tensorflow_env_Installation)

or

```
    echo 'Name of the TENSORFLOW ENVIRONMENT:'
    read ENVNAME

    #CREATING THE ENV
    conda create --name $ENVNAME -y

    #ACTIVATE THE eNV
    conda activate $ENVNAME6

    # INSTALLING CUDA DRIVERS
    conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0 -y

    # INSTALLING TENSORFLOW
    conda install tensorflow-gpu -y
    conda install -c anaconda ipykernel -y
    conda install ipykernel -y

    # ADDING ENV TO JUPYTER LIST
    python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=$ENVNAME

    # 'VERIFY GPU SUPPORT'
    python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; 
    print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```