# tensorflow-gpu - pycharm doesn't recognize GPU

Tags: tensorflow

i've imported tensorflow gpu, but `pycharm` doesn't recognize it

details:

```
IDE -pycharm
GPU- grid p40-1Q
cuda - 8
cudnn - 7.1
python - 3.5
```

i'm getting this message:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run it outside of pycharm terminal?

Comment: i tried it also in spyder and anaconda prompt, and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with

> nvidia-smi

and see if your graphic driver is working? Also, have you checked the version of your tensorflow-gpu ? check for compatible configurations here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_source_configurations

I tried with the following configuration on pycharm with windows 10 and it worked!!

1. Anaconda navigator with python 3.6.8
2. CUDA 9.0
3. CUDNN 7.1
4. Nvidia GeForce 1050 Ti GPU

Follow the instructions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51307381/2562870