# Installing tensorflow-gpu on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm new in python, I have python 3.5, windows 10, AVX 5200. I want to install tensorflow on gpu. I tried vary blogs step by step, but I cannot get tensorflow on gpu, always get the following message:

```
    Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
```

please can anyone help me how can I get tensorflow-gpu step by step? I will be thankfull to him.

Comment: It is possible that you successfully install tensorflow-gpu, but your code gets to use tensorflow-cpu nonetheless, e.g., because of some environment setting. When you do `pip install tensorflow-gpu`, does the installation complete successfully?

Comment: @InonPeled thank you for your reply. yes it says the installation complete successfully, but when I train the CNN model in python with pycharm, It give me this message. How can I enable my CNN to train and evaluate data using tensorflow-gpu, it is very slow and stuck with my tensorflow, can you please help me?

Comment: Maybe start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-to-use-tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use TensorFlow GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-to-use-tensorflow-gpu)

Comment: @InonPeled I'm followed what is mentioned, but I get:  I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
2019-04-02 20:26:49.174284: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties:
name: NVS 5200M major: 2 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.344
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.00GiB freeMemory: 823.00MiB

Comment: 2019-04-02 20:26:49.174641: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1168] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: NVS 5200M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 2.1) with Cuda compute capability 2.1. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.0.
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 15798718000949594164
]

Comment: So it appears that you need to upgrade your CUDA libs. Again, refer to the instructions in the link that I pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have installed and get TF running.
2. You are seeing a warning message, not an error at all. You have installed a precompiled package, which didn't enable AVX instruction set, AVX is SIMD instruction set of C.P.U.
3. You may ensure tensorflow gpu is working by run:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
sess.close()
```

4. Highly recommend using ananconda and install everything with conda.
5. Find a book or just read the official guides.