# how to check if tenserflow is using gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am using Jupyter notebook for training neural network. I choose in the anaconda applications on tenserflow-gpu however I dont think it is using GPU. How can I check it if it is using GPU for processing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use TensorFlow GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-to-use-tensorflow-gpu)

Comment: let me try instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the

```
<tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')>
```

For tensorflow 2.1.
Also check the documentation found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/list_physical_devices)

Comment: it gives empty list, which means it doesn't use gpu right ?

Comment: It would appear so