# How to use GPU in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow-GPU but it seems to be still running on the CPU. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-to-use-tensorflow-gpu) Question on how to install Tensorflow-GPU and everything seems right until I try to verify it by executing

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

When I do that then I get following output:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4000308941676664793
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 7883418274751980843
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 13103704949076676658
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

Tensorflow only seems to find my CPU and apparently a XLA_CPU and a XLA_GPU. Do I just have to set the GPU manually or have I done anything wrong? I'm using a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti BTW.

Comment: What is the outcome of these prints? `value = tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False,
    min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)
print ('***If TF can access GPU: ***\n',value)
print ("Number of GPUs: ",len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

Comment: First some deprecation notes and the following:

***If TF can access GPU: ***
 False
Number of GPUs:  0


​

Comment: That means TF can not see your GPU. The installations haven't been done properly. Please follow this [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only CUDA version 10.1 works. Version 9 and 10.2 are not compatible with the latest version of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should confirm whether the NVIDIA drive, cuda and cudnn is installed and their version

Comment: Checked everything again and CUDA and CUDnn is definetly installed, the driver of the GPU is also on the newest version

Comment: e....when I use tensorflow2.0, I added code below in training scripts: 

```python
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```
I hope it can help you.