# Use GPU in VSCode for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I've followed this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-do-i-use-tensorflow-gpu#:%7E:text=Follow%20this%20tutorial,by%20simple%20program). Then, I've tried this [nvidia steps](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#:%7E:text=the%20following%20command%3A-,conda%20install%20cuda%20%2Dc%20nvidia,-2.4.3.%C2%A0Uninstallation) (`conda install cuda -c nvidia`) to install it in a conda env. But when I try

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
# output: []
```

I have a 3070 GPU. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Install Tensorflow-gpu using conda with these steps`conda create -n tf_gpu python=3.9` and `conda activate tf_gpu` and `conda install cudatoolkit==11.2` and `pip install tensorflow`. Verify installation `import tensorflow as tf` and `print(len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip and follow the procedure. Most likely you did not provide some of software requirements. I had the same issue when i did not install the cuda toolkit. After installing cuda and cudnn it was fixed for me.