# How make tensorflow use GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm working with python and I would like to use tensorflow with my GTX2080TI but tensorflow is using only the CPU.

when I ask for device on my computer, it always return an empty list:

```
In [3]: tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
Out[3]: []
```

I try this post: [How do I use TensorFlow GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306862/how-do-i-use-tensorflow-gpu)
but I don't use cuda and the tennsorflow-gpu seems outdated.

I also try this well done tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0 without success.

I install the card drivers, CUDA and cudNN but I still get the same issue.
I also unsinstall tensorflow and keras an install them again without success.

I don't know how can I find what is missing or if I made something wrong.

Python 3.10
Tensoflow version: 2.11.0
Cuda version: 11.2
cudNN: 8.1

This line code tell's me that cuda is not build:

```
print(tf_build_info.build_info) 
OrderedDict([('is_cuda_build', False), ('is_rocm_build', False), ('is_tensorrt_build', False), ('msvcp_dll_names', 'msvcp140.dll,msvcp140_1.dll')])
```

Comment: Can you include TensorFlow, CUDA, and cudNN versions in the question? It will help people to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes, sure. I added them

Answer (score 1):

Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, GPU support was dropped for native windows. You can optionally use [Direct ML Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#tensorflow-directml-plugin-)
Tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np11T5-_KhA)